# EF Code First - Seeding data that needs foreign key reference

Tags: .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have 2 entities - Roles and Administrators. Roles has two values - Search Admin and Super Admin. I have created these using EF Code First model. Now I am trying to seed values to the database and I add the roles first:

```
    private static void SeedRoles(PayByPhoneDbContext context)
    {
        var roles = new List<Role> {new Role {Name = "Search Administrator"}, new Role {Name = "Super Administrator"}};
        roles.ForEach(role => context.Roles.Add(role));
    }
```

Now I want to use one of the roles created above to be used while adding administrators:

```
    private void SeedAdministrators(PayByPhoneDbContext context)
    {
        var administrators = new List<Administrator>{new Administrator {Email = "a@a.com", Name = "Achinth Gurkhi", Password = "hello", Active = true, Role = ? }}
    }
```

How do I set Role here? Should I say `Role = new Role { Name = "Super Administrator" }` or search for Role inserted by SeedRoles method? Also, how do I search for an existing role using the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both methods are called before you execute `SaveChanges` on your context you must use the same role instance you created in `SeedRoles` otherwise you will create another `Role` with the same name. You must either pass created role / roles to `SeedAdministrators` (which is correct approach) or you can try to query `context.Roles.Local.Where(r => r.Name = "...")` and search for the role.

Comment: the context.Roles.Local does not have a Where method.

Comment: It is extension method. You must use `using System.Linq;`